# Remove certain records from a set of records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Question - how to remove certain records from LINQ, like i have some records i wanted them to be removed from my LINQ.

Scenario - i have table A with 10 records and table B with 2 records i want to remove records that are belong to B to be removed from A [using linq] 
-below i have all the records in q and i want to remove the records that are there in p.

```
var p = from c in q
        join dr in dc.TableData on c.Id equals dr.CaseId
        select new View()
        {
            ActiveCaseId = c.ActiveCaseId,
            Id = c.Id                            
        };

q = q.Except(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the `Except` as you show, because `p` and `q` are different types. But it would also be a bit clumsy.

You can do it in one query:

```cs
var p = from c in q
        where !dc.TableData.Any(dr => dr.CaseId == c.Id)
                        select new View()
                        {
                            ActiveCaseId = c.ActiveCaseId,
                            Id = c.Id                            
                        };
```